# Is there a bijection $f:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$ s.t. $f'(x)=f^{-1}(x)$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

> Is there a bijection $f:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$ s.t. $f'(x)=f^{-1}(x)$?

And if there is, can I prove uniqueness? This problem troubles me.

Comment: Well, what I got out of math club was that this does exist, $f(x)=\phi^{-\frac\phi{\phi+1}}x^\phi$, but not sure how I was meant to determine that, or find uniqueness.